# Using gradle to conditionally add beans to a spring project

Tags: java, spring, gradle, dependencies, multi-module

I'm trying to think of a way to conditionally add (or augment) behaviour in my Spring boot project. The use-case is such: When a project is built for a particular customer, they have custom functionality requirements. I don't want the (unused) custom functionality class files to exist in the deployment for other customers, so I'm thinking about a multi module project that's using a gradle build argument to include the custom functionality module. However, I think there's a circular dependency issue where the custom functionality depends on components from the main project - but to include the custom functionality in the build, the main project has to depend on the custom module. I've tried including the module in the parent gradle.settings, having the module depend on the main project and then using the same package name and structure as what exists in the main project in a hopeful attempt that classpath scanning would pick up the class and create the bean - but it seems unless I have the main project depend on the custom code it doesn't seem to want to work.

Is there something simple I've missed or a better way to go about what I'm trying to do?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a simple and effective way to do it:

```
if (project.hasProperty("feature-a")) {
    runtimeOnly project(':feature-a')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying your application using the Springboot "fat-jar" created by the  `bootJar` task?  if so, one solution would be to conditionally include the feature module librarie(s) inside this Springboot jar, at the expected location  ( under `BOOT-INF/lib` where all other dependent libraries from your main project will be located).
This way, your feature module library will be scanned at application startup, and your custom beans will be found (if you respect the package naming as you mentioned).

A sample configuration that can be used to configure the Spring jar content:

```
if (project.hasProperty("feature-a")) {
    project(":feature-a").afterEvaluate { featureAproject->
        bootJar {
            into("BOOT-INF/lib") {
                // note: there might be other ways to reference the output jar from subproject                
                from(featureAproject.tasks.getByName("jar").outputs)

                // TODO : create task dependency between bootJar task and the 'jar' task from feature subproject
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, it does suit my use-case and works well.
However I have also found another way which requires minimal changes and works across all tasks (such as bootWar and bootRun), and that is by conditionally declaring the feature project dependency as runtimeOnly in the main project

Comment: using conditional dependency in `runtimeOnly` is a clever solution, this will indeed avoid the module dependency cycle.  you should post an answer to your own question